# highcharts xAxis label set 0.5% step

Tags: highcharts

I have a scatter chart below. It has default step as 1%. But I want to set xAxis for every 0.5% step. How can I do that? Fiddler link:http://jsfiddle.net/vpBj7/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {        
        'labels': {
            'format': '{value}%',
            'step':0.5
     }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2,30]        
    }]

});
```

});

[image]

Comment: please provide your code or fiddle..to check..you will have XAxis variable there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `tickInterval` as 0.5

http://jsfiddle.net/vpBj7/1/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Bochan!!